# Access Query Group by Error (language change from English to unknown characters)

Tags: database, ms-access, syntax-error

I'm trying to run a query in MS access, this query reads the data from another query and a table, all the tables do not have a single unknown character, it only have Employees ID, Email and names with department code and description ALL in ENGLISH.

The query works fine, but when I add the "group by" formula, the names and emails change to something unreadable (picture attached)!

[enter image description here][1]

here under is the sql, yet I don't understand why does this happen at all. would you please help?

```
SELECT [Empl ID+Dept ID].EmplID, [Empl ID+Dept ID].Unit, [Empl ID+Dept ID].Name, [Empl ID+Dept ID].Group, [Empl ID+Dept ID].[Employee Record], [Empl ID+Dept ID].DEPTID, [DACSS DSAs].[SAR Department Title], [DACSS DSAs].Hire, [DACSS DSAs].[I\A], [DACSS DSAs].[User Name], [DACSS DSAs].[Email Address]
FROM [Empl ID+Dept ID] LEFT JOIN [DACSS DSAs] ON [Empl ID+Dept ID].DEPTID = [DACSS DSAs].[SAR Department Code]
GROUP BY [Empl ID+Dept ID].EmplID, [Empl ID+Dept ID].Unit, [Empl ID+Dept ID].Name, [Empl ID+Dept ID].Group, [Empl ID+Dept ID].[Employee Record], [Empl ID+Dept ID].DEPTID, [DACSS DSAs].[SAR Department Title], [DACSS DSAs].Hire, [DACSS DSAs].[I\A], [DACSS DSAs].[User Name], [DACSS DSAs].[Email Address]
HAVING ((([DACSS DSAs].Hire)="Hire") AND (Not ([DACSS DSAs].[I\A])="Null"));
```

Comment: The picture is missing and you might benefit from reading 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613)

Answer (score 0):

Don't group by Memo (LongText) columns:
[Grouping by Memo field yields garbage](http://allenbrowne.com/bug-18.html)

Actually, you don't have any aggregate functions, so turn off grouping altogether in this query.